# iframe html no found path with char Ñ

Tags: html, jsf, iframe, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using iframe to display a PDF `<iframe>` in my xhtml, I'm using PrimeFaces. In my bean, I get the file path and I recovered well, but when I have a pdf that contains character Ñ not find me. I tried to use `new String (s, "UTF-8")` but didn't work, I also tried to put in my xhtml:

```
  <? xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8">
```

But didn't work either.

Significantly, before recovering the print file path with `System.out.println` and if I printed with the character Ñ.

```
<p:panel>
    <iframe id="frmDocumentoView" title="Documento"                            
        name="frmDocumentoView" src="..#{loteBean.obtenerRutaValida}"                                      
        frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"                                      
        scrolling="auto" height="560px" width="720px">
        Su Navegador no soporta Frames 
    </iframe>
</p:panel>
```

Comment: If you're already using PrimeFaces, why to use an `<iframe>` to load PDF when you have `<p:media>`? Look at the component sample that shows a PDF file: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/media.jsf

Comment: Also, have you tried copying the URL and pasting directly in the browser to check if its available? Note that you may get `%D1` instead of `Ñ` and `%F1` instead of `ñ`, noted by [HTML URL Encoding](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp).